# Is it possible to create a grid of five figures like four squares at the corners and one at the middle?

Tags: floats

I am wondering if it's possible to create a grid of figures like the example below?

[image]

Comment: was the answer meeting the requirements

Comment: would you like to accept the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit,decorations.pathreplacing, intersections, 
fadings, positioning}  % TikZ libraries
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node(picA)[xshift=-2cm,yshift=-2cm, label=-90:Caption1] at (current 
    page.center){%
    {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{photo.png}}};
    \node(picB)[xshift=4cm,label=-90:Caption2] at (picA.center){%
    {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{photo.png}}};
    \node(picB)[yshift=4cm,label=-90:Caption3] at (picA.center){%
    {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{photo.png}}};
    \node(picB)[xshift=4cm, yshift=4cm,label=-90:Caption4] at (picA.center){%
    {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{photo.png}}};
    \node(picB)[xshift=2cm, yshift=2cm] at (picA.center){%
    {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{photo.png}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but would you be able to put some sort of captions for the four peripheral figures as well? like (a) (b) (c) (d)

Comment: edited the code added `label=angle:caption1`

Comment: I am gonna wait for a while, and then I would accept an answer. Just saying. Thank you my friend!